# how to use Loop to verificate if an object bounds Intersetcs with another objects Bounds in c# WF?

Tags: c#, wpf, 2d

how can i transform this series of if to loop?

I am making a 2D game in Windows form, and I want to check if one of the 5 bullets hit one of the 5 enemies, but I want to know which bullet hit and which enemy was hit! (i know the logic how to do it but i just want to do it with loop and not with 25 if)
Thanks!

```
if (bulletOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyOne.Bounds) || bulletTwo.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyOne.Bounds) || bulletThree.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyOne.Bounds) || bulletFour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyOne.Bounds) || bulletFive.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyOne.Bounds))
{
    enemyOne.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
}
if (bulletOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyTwo.Bounds) || bulletTwo.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyTwo.Bounds) || bulletThree.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyTwo.Bounds) || bulletFour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyTwo.Bounds) || bulletFive.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyTwo.Bounds))
{
    enemyTwo.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
}
if (bulletOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyThree.Bounds) || bulletTwo.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyThree.Bounds) || bulletThree.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyThree.Bounds) || bulletFour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyThree.Bounds) || bulletFive.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyThree.Bounds))
{
    enemyThree.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
}
if (bulletOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFour.Bounds) || bulletTwo.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFour.Bounds) || bulletThree.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFour.Bounds) || bulletFour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFour.Bounds) || bulletFive.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFour.Bounds))
{
    enemyFour.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
}
if (bulletOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFive.Bounds) || bulletTwo.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFive.Bounds) || bulletThree.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFive.Bounds) || bulletFour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFive.Bounds) || bulletFive.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemyFive.Bounds))
{
    enemyFive.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the bullets and the enemies in a list, and then loop through that list.
That way, you can have all the bullets check through all the enemies in a single loop.

But in order to put them in a List, you should make use of classes, that way you can make an object out of them, to call them multiple times.

For example:

```
//note: 'Enemy' and 'Bullet' are class names, so they'll need to be defined in a seperate class
List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();
List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();

//fill your lists in the way you want them to spawn, example below:
bullets.Add(new Bullet(/*place your bullet variables here*/));
enemies.Add(new Enemy(/*place your enemy variables here*/));

//loop
foreach (Bullet b in bullets)
{
    foreach (Enemy e in enemies)
    {
        if (b.Bounds.IntersectsWith(e))
        {
            e.Left = rnd.Next(1300, 1400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, as a sidenote: Seeing you using Windows Forms reminds me of my first time trying to make a game with it. It's fun to experiment, but remember that Windows Forms isn't exactly made to make games. Consider using XNA or Monogame (These engines also works with Visual Studio) before you struggle with Windows Form's limitations.

Comment: thanks, but i know wf its not made for games but its an homework for school. i like 3d games so im using unity